# Calculations failed because of - nan

Tags: c++

My exercise is to write code which will print the value of this phrase
[image]

I have written a code which should work, but when I try to print a value I receive "the value is -nan".

```
//My Code
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    double y;
    double x = 21;


   y = 30 * sqrt(x * (1/(tan(sqrt(3*x) - 2.1))));

  printf ("The value is: \n=> %f", y );


}
```

My question is how can I print the proper value?

Comment: nan means "not a number". For example if you take the square root of a negative number, the result is nan.

Comment: y = 30 * sqrt(x * (1/(tan(sqrt(3*x) - 2.1)))); - is it correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that, depending on the unit ([radians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian) or [degrees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_(angle))), you get different results with trigonometric functions. Keep in mind that the `tan` function [expects its argument in radians](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/tan).

`sqrt(3*21)-2.1 = 5.837`, and you have to calculate its tangent. It is indeed negative if we work with radians (it is around `-0.478`), leading to the square root of a negative number which is `NaN` (Not a Number), but if you use degrees then it is `+0.102` and you can complete the calculation. If you want to have the result you would have with degrees, considering the function accepts radians, you must convert the number. The conversion is simple: multiply by Pi and divide by 180. Like this:

```
y = 30 * sqrt(x * (1/(tan((sqrt(3*x) - 2.1)*M_PI/180))));
```

In this case the result is `429.967`.

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
printf( "sqrt(3*x) = %lf\n", sqrt(3*x));
printf( "sqrt(3*x) - 2.1 = %lf\n", sqrt(3*x) - 2.1);
printf( "tan(sqrt(3*x) - 2.1) = %lf\n", tan(sqrt(3*x) - 2.1));
```

then you will notice that the last one is negative which will result in a sqrt of a negative number, thus the NaN

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit it's not, it was just a side comment regarding his use of printf. His main problem is the negative sqrt

Comment: Okay well there is nothing wrong with the `printf` so that's just confusing!

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is not related with conversion to *radians*, i.e. multiplication by `M_PI / 180.`

In general, operations that produce `NaN` (Not a Number)<sup>1</sup> are:

[image]

In your case the result of `tan()` is negative which leads to negative input value for the outer `sqrt()`, which is the last example from the above table.

To resolve the problematic situation you could either use some mathematical trick<sup>2</sup> and try to rewrite the expression such that it doesn't produce a NaN, or if the problem is in the negative square root, you can use the `#include <complex>` and:

```
std::complex<double> two_i = std::sqrt(std::complex<double>(-4));
```

The rest of the answers provide you with a strategy of how to identify the NaN source, by checking each computation involved

---

<sup>1. Bit patterns reserved for special quantities to handle exceptional situations like taking the square root of a negative number, other than aborting computation are called `NaN`s.</sup>

<sup>2. Use trigonometric relations.</sup>

<sup>where `#define M_PI = 3.14159265358979323846;`</sup>